# pugixml number of child nodes

Tags: xml-parsing, count, size, pugixml

Does a pugixml node object have a number-of-child-nodes method? I cannot find it in the documentation and had to use an iterator as follows:

```
int n = 0;
for (pugi::xml_node ch_node = xMainNode.child("name"); ch_node; ch_node = ch_node.next_sibling("name")) n++;
```

Comment: No worries, I restored it just now before I read your message here. Thank you for the excellent code!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no built-in function to compute that directly; one other approach is to use `std::distance`:

```
size_t n = std::distance(xMainNode.children("name").begin(), xMainNode.children("name").end());
```

Of course, this is linear in the number of child nodes; note that computing the number of all child nodes, `std::distance(xMainNode.begin(), xMainNode.end())`, is also linear - there is no constant-time access to child node count.

Comment: Note: This is the author of pugixml.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an expression based on an xpath search (no efficiency guarantees, though):

```
xMainNode.select_nodes( "name" ).size()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int children_count(pugi::xml_node node)
{
  int n = 0;
  for (pugi::xml_node child : node.children()) n++;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: I think you should explain your answer